# Calculating mesh centers runs very slowly

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a piece of code that is used to calculate the cell centers in a rectangular mesh. The mesh size is pretty large (650 columns by 1150 rows). The code runs very slowly. I was wondering if I could employ any tricks to reduce the runtime.

In the example below, `deltax` is a 1D array of column spacings and `deltay` is a 1D array of row spacings. Maybe I need to do some sort of vectorization.

```
center_x = np.empty((nrow,ncol),dtype ='double')
center_y = np.empty((nrow,ncol),dtype ='double')
for i in range(nrow-1,-1,-1):
    if(i == nrow-1):
        center_y[i,:] = 0.5*deltay[nrow-1]
    else:
        center_y[i,:] = center_y[i+1,:] + 0.5*deltay[i+1] + 0.5*deltay[i]

for j in range(0,ncol):
    if(j ==0):
        center_x[:,j] = 0.5*deltax[0]
    else:
        center_x[:,j]= center_x[0,j-1] + 0.5*deltax[j-1] + 0.5*deltax[j]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things I would try to change:

- Is it necessary, that `center_x` and `center_y` are 2-dimensional arrays? In your code, the 2nd dimension holds redundant information and should be avoided.
- The biggest problem with pure Python (but often the greatest benefit ;) ) is that it is an interpreted language and numerically heavy operations should be handled with library functions. In your case, I would try to exploit `numpy`'s array features and calculate the center as

  ```
  center_x = 0.5 * (delta_x[:ncol-1] + delta_x[1:])
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is necessary that the centers be 2D arrays. I agree that the second dimension is redundant for the case I posted: a grid without rotation. However, I have to account for grid rotation as well which would result in different x coordinates for the same column and different y coordinates for the same row. I will try your suggestion about exploiting numpy's array features.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the mesh is *rectangular*, then you don't need to calculate the center of *every cell*: you just need the x-coordinates of the centers of the columns, and the y-coordinates of the centers of the rows. If you then need the whole grid of centers, you can pass the column and row centers to [`numpy.meshgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html).
2. You can vectorize the computation using [`numpy.cumsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) to find the cumulative sums of the row and column spacings:

   ```
   center_x, center_y = np.meshgrid(np.cumsum(deltax) + 0.5 * deltax,
                                    np.cumsum(deltay) + 0.5 * deltay)
   ```